# HTML - Checking for a correct answer for a random math equation

Tags: html, random, input

I have a code that randomly shows a picture on the screen:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var imageURLs = [
       "www._.com/test.jpg" 
     , "www._.com/test.jpg"
     , "www._.com/test.jpg"
  ];
  function getImageTag() {
    var img = '<img src=\"';
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
    img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
    img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
    return img;

  }
</script>


</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(getImageTag());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Each picture is a math problem. How do I assign each picture a different solution and put an input box that checks weather the input matches it depending on the displayed picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it this way..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var imageURLs = [
    "1.png" 
    , "2.png"
    , "3.png"
    ];
    var answer = [  // create the answer array
    "brown" 
    , "blue"
    , "green"
    ];
    // make randomIndex global
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);

    // set image based on randomIndex
    function getImageTag() {
    var img = '<img src=\"';
    img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
    img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
    return img;
    }

    // check answer based on randomIndex
    function checkAnswer() {
    var ans = document.getElementById("in").value;
    if(ans == answer[randomIndex])
    alert("Hooray!");
    else
    alert("Try again");
    }
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(getImageTag());
    </script>
    <br>
        <input type="text" id="in"/>
        <!-- Call checkAnswer() to verify-->
        <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="checkAnswer()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The main concept is like this..

1. It's the same way you are creating the image except we make the random index a global variable
2. You are choosing the image based on the random Index stored in a global array, similarly we are choosing the answer based on the index also stored previously in a matching fashion in a global array.
3. Whenever the user is giving the answer we are checking it using the previous concept.

Hope this clarifies what I did. If there are still confusions please comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! This really helped